# Unable to stop code execution when a variable becomes 0

Tags: php

I am writing this code to distribute given no. of guests and childs in given no. of rooms with following conditions:

1. One room cannot contain more than 4 guests including adults and childs.
2. Guests will be placed in next room up to max 3 if a room gets 4 guests.
3. Guests can opt for placing less than 4 guests in a room in which case less than 4 guests can be allotted in a room.

Code:

```
$adults = 5;
$childs = 4;
$rooms = 3;

$dist = distGuests($adults, $childs, $rooms);

function distGuests($adults, $childs, $rooms) {
    $dist = array();
    $i = 0;
    $j = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rooms;) {
        if ($adults) {
            $dist['adults'][$i] +=  $j;
            $adults--;
        }
        if ($childs) {
            echo 'Hi!<br>';
            $dist['childs'][$i] += $j;
        } else {
            echo 'Bye!<br>';
        }
        $childs--;
        if (($dist['adults'][$i] + $dist['childs'][$i]) == 4) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $dist;
}
```

This should print as follows:

```
Array
(
    [adults] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [childs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

But it is printing as follows i.e., code execution not stopping when $child becomes 0:

```
Array
(
    [adults] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [childs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Please tell me what I am missing in this?

Thanks,

Comment: your expected and what you currently get is exactly same. So what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry! Corrected the incorrect output. Please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move

```
 $childs--;
```

below

```
 $dist['childs'][$i] += $j;
```

so that it is within the if statement and is not always called (which makes its value fall below 0)

at the end of your for loop add:

```
if(!($adults) and !($childs) ){
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did try that and if I move $childs-- below  $dist['childs'][$i] += $j;, it goes in an indefinite loop till time out.

Comment: @ShyamSingh your missing a check to see if both $childs and $adults are 0 to end the outer for  loop. add that in and you should be good to go. ill add an edit explaining it